# React - how to compare prev and current state that is based on API

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state

I am preparing a game in which the player, based on the presented card, has to decide whether the next one will be higher or lower than the previous one. Every round, data(card value and image) is pulled from the API https://deckofcardsapi.com/.

I have a problem, how can I compare the old and new condition if the data is downloaded from the API.

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import Card from './components/Card/Card';
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import HistoryTable from './components/HistoryTable/HistoryTable';
import './App.scss';
import Buttons from './components/Buttons/Buttons';
import Stats from './components/Stats/Stats';

function App() {
  const [card, setCard] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [httpError, setHttpError] = useState();
  const [roundNumber, setRoundNumber] = useState(1);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  function handleHigherClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRoundNumber((prevState) => ++prevState);
//How can I compare new state with previous?
  }

  function handleLowerClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setRoundNumber((prevState) => ++prevState);
//How can I compare new state with previous?
  }

  const fetchCard = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setHttpError(null);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/draw/?count=1'
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
      }

      const responseData = await response.json();
      const data = responseData.cards[0];

      setCard({
        value: data.value,
        image: data.image,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setHttpError(error.message);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCard();
  }, [roundNumber, fetchCard]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Stats round={roundNumber} score={score} />
        <Card
          value={card.value}
          image={card.image}
          loading={isLoading}
          error={httpError}
        />
        {roundNumber !== 30 ? (
          <Buttons higher={handleHigherClick} lower={handleLowerClick} />
        ) : (
          <Buttons />
        )}
        <HistoryTable />
      </main>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you can pass prev as a param to a set function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you will have to do this manually, storing the result of each fetch in a structure that allows you to do this comparison.
A two-position array seems to me the most ideal form.
Maybe you can manipulate this structure using just `.pop()` and `.shift()`